# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am using MongoDB as my database for my Reactjs project. Here, when I am trying to connect the database, it gives me this error - "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" 
Here's the code of App.js

```
 import React from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Feed from "./Feed";
import Widgets from "./Widgets";
import "./App.css";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

function App() {
  // Connection URI
  const uri =
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  // Create a new MongoClient
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);
  async function run() {
    try {
      // Connect the client to the server
      await client.connect();
      // Establish and verify connection
      await client.db("posts").command({ ping: 1 });
      console.log("Connected successfully to server");
    } finally {
      // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
      await client.close();
    }
  }
  run();

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Sidebar />
      <Feed />
      <Widgets />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a backend for your React app and connect to database from there. Then expose an endpoint like /api/posts and call that in your React app with fetch or something similar, e.g.

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(posts => console.log(posts));
```

Comment: Is there any other way to integrate?

Comment: No. It's not possible to connect directly to the database from the web browser. And even if it was, you shouldn't do that because then every visitor would have access to your database credentials and that would not be secure at all.